# Set current time to yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to ask about `NSDate`, how to set/format current time like "2015-08-12 09:30:41 +0000" to "2015-08-12 00:00:00 +0000

I'm already using :

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
//result date will be : Aug 12, 2015
```

but the value date is not stored  in the Database exactly as "2015-08-12 00:00:00 +0000" but storing as "2015-08-11 17:00:00 +0000 UTC"

Comment: You could use `dateFormat` property of `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: how to use dateformat? dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00"?

Comment: Correct.Change it as per your need.

Comment: i try at playground, use format "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 " the result is nil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 4 or later**

```
let dateString = "2019-05-04 09:30:41 +0000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString.components(separatedBy: " ").first ?? "") {
    print(dateFromString)  // "2019-05-04 00:00:00 +0000"
}
```

Comment: There's a potential bug in this solution. When you parse the dateString to a NSDate object, you omitted the timeZone info, thus, if you have an input dateString such as "2015-08-12 23:30:41 -0900", it will generate "2015-08-12 00:00:00 +0000" as output, whereas the correct output should be "2015-08-13 00:00:00 +0000"

Comment: @LeoDabus well, I just want to emphasize the fact that you've given a buggy solution, and it's been taken as a correct answer. If no one discover that, it would cause potential damages to people who took this answer without thinking about it. So, nothing personal, really.:)

Comment: You are finding hair on eggs

Comment: Bugs are always hair on eggs. Don't you agree?

Comment: No I don't.  There is no bug

Comment: Learning something new from this answer. There is no bug it returns `2015-08-12 00:00:00 +0000` Cheers !

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to remove the time portion from an NSDate instance is

```
let startOfDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
```

To get the date depending on the current time zone use

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
let startOfDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
println(startOfDate)
```

#### Swift 4

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
let startOfDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
print(startOfDate)
```

Comment: but if i println("\(startOfDate)") why result date : 2015-08-11 17:00:00 +0000

Comment: NSDate has no idea about the time zone you're living in. printing out the current date with  `println(NSDate())`  prints also the date in UTC

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the timezone on user's device, i.e, you are not going to save that formatted date string to server, etc, then, you can use the following code:

```
var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 Z"
formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

If you want to save that date string to server as well, then, you should add timezone info to the formatter:

```
var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 Z"
formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

**Update**

Now I understand what you actually wanted to do, you have a date string instead of a NSDate object as an input.

You can use the following code for achieving your desired output, **with respect to preserving timezone info of the input**.

```
let dateString = "2015-08-12 09:30:41 +0000"
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

let inputDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"
inputDateFormatter.calendar = calendar

if let inputDate = inputDateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
    let outPutDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    outPutDateFormatter.calendar = calendar
    outPutDateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
    outPutDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 Z"
    print(outPutDateFormatter.stringFromDate(inputDate))
}
```

Comment: i already try using your format suggest , i input 2015-08-13 hh:mm:ss (current time) , format using your format but in database, value date is 2015-08-12 17:00:00 +0000

Comment: Did you make sure that the hour/minute/second format is hardcoded? It's impossible to output the hour value in the formatted string if you use the same formatted provided above. Could you try to print the formatted date string on Xcode debugging console and confirm that?